# The name 'hello' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have this in Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ApprovalProcess._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        Hello, it's working <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
    <script>
        alert("<%= hello%>");
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

And this is Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace ApprovalProcess
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        String hello = "hello";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

The following is my error

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'hello' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a visibility it defaults to private. The view cannot see the `hello` variable because the view is actually a class that inherits from your code-behind class. You need to declare it as either `protected` or `public` depending on how visible you want it to be (likely `protected` would be correct in this case).

```
protected string hello = "hello";
```

or

```
public string hello = "hello";
```

It might be enlightening for you to read up on member visibility to understand what the options mean so you can make informed choices as you continue to develop.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Member_accessibility

Comment: Change `String hello = "hello";` to `protected String hello = "hello";` or `public String hello = "hello";`